# Consuming JSON using Express 4.11 and bodyParser

Tags: json, node.js, express, body-parser

I am going nuts on this, I have spent hours on Stackoverflow and the net in general, tried this that and the other, and still cannot get a result.

I'm a (very) newb on node.js, but have successfully followed a tutorial to build a (very) simple form using `bodyParser.urlencoded`, and I can successfully recover and display the posted data. Now I want to do the same using `bodyParser.json()` - but no matter what I try, the result is always empty.

Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

var app = express();


// JSON testing
app.post('/json-test', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log(req.body.title);
    res.status(200).send(req.body.title);
    })

// Can't get anything else
.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
    })


.listen(8090);
```

Here is the curl request

```
$curl -X POST -H "application/json" -d '{"title":"test-title"}' http://localhost:8090/json-test
```

The result of the first console.log is `{}` and of the second just `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect curl request, need add "Content-Type":

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"title":"test-title"}' http://localhost:8090/json-test
```